# Vaadin Bean validation for table

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

When I enter edit mode of my Table, **I want to have data validation on all fields in that Table**.

First, a couple of notes:

- I'm using Vaadin 7, so the Bean Validation addon sadly won't work.
- I know the implementation of JSR-303 works, because I tried adding a BeanValidator to a TextField without issues.

Now, I have a perfectly working table for which I am using a BeanItemContainer to keep my Person beans inside.

The Person bean looks as follows:

```
public class Person {

    @Size(min = 5, max = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(min = 5, max = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Min(0)
    @Max(2000)
    private int description;

    ... getters + setters...
}
```

Person beans are added to the BeanItemContainer, which in turn is set to the container data source with setContainerDataSource()

The BeanValidator was added to the table like so:

```
table.addValidator(new BeanValidator(Person.class, "firstName"));
```

When I run the application, I have two problems:

1. When I run the application, the table shows up as intended. However, when I edit the fields and set one of the firstName fields to, say, "abc" - no validation error is shown and the value is accepted
   **How am I supposed to get BeanValidator to work on all of my tables fields?**
2. When I use table.setSelectable(true) or table.setMultiSelect(true), I get this error:

   > com.vaadin.server.ServiceException:
   >   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [] is not a valid value for
   >   property firstName of type class
   >   com.some.path.vaadinpoc.sampleapp.web.Person
   >   **How am I supposed to get BeanValidator to work with Selectable/MultiSelect?**

Please advice

Thanks!

Comment: It will be useful to see: a) declaration of `Person.firstName` field, b) problematic values of this field

Comment: The Person class is now added to my original question.

Also, I found the cause of one problem (the exception), but it is still not working. I have updated my original question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add the validators to the editable fields themselves, not to the table. (Table itself is a field => the Validator from `table.addValidator` validates the value of the Table => the value of the table is the selected itemId(s) => the BeanValidator fails)

You can add the validators to the fields that by using a custom TableFieldFactory on the table. Here's a very simple one-off example for this scenario - clearly, if you need to do this with a lot of different beans/tables, it'll be worth creating a more generic/customizable factory

```
  table.setTableFieldFactory(new DefaultFieldFactory() {
  @Override
  public Field<?> createField(Item item, Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
    Field<?> field = super.createField(item, propertyId, uiContext);
    if (propertyId.equals("firstName")) {
      field.addValidator(new BeanValidator(Person.class, "firstName"));
    }
    if (propertyId.equals("lastName")) {
      field.addValidator(new BeanValidator(Person.class, "lastName"));
    }
    if (propertyId.equals("description")) {
      field.addValidator(new BeanValidator(Person.class, "description"));
    }
    return field;
  }
```

Comment: Of course. This sounds quite obvious. I will give it a try asap and come back with results. Thanks Charles!

Comment: It works! But only when I pre-load the table with invalid values, though (a red text is shown, indicating what's wrong). 

When I edit the table and change from a valid value to an invalid value, it wont accept it - as intended, but on the other hand a validation error tooltip will NOT be shown. 

The next question is why the red exclamation mark is not shown, but that may be out of scope for this question.

Comment: Got the warning text now. I had to make it an AbstractField and use setImmediate(true). Still I have to press enter in the textfield and mousover for the tooltip to appear.

Comment: Unfortunately the same solution doesn't work for me:`table.setTableFieldFactory(new AddBeanFieldFactory<EnumValueDescriptor>(EnumValueDescriptor.class){
@Override
public Field<?> createField(Container container, final Object itemId,
Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
Field<?> field = super.createField(container, itemId, propertyId, uiContext);
field.addValidator(new Validator(){
@Override
public void validate(Object value)
throws InvalidValueException {throw new InvalidValueException("test");
}});` changes the table behavior: I need to set the value twice to set it(1st time it disappear